# jQuery/jQueryUI conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using some jquery files for auto complete and datetime picker control but 3 files among them are conflicting:

1. Two files for autocomplete are

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. One file for Calender datetime picker is:

   ```
   <script  src="../assets/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
   ```

These 3 files are confilicting  when i comment date time picker file autocomplete works and if I uncomment it autocomplete stops.

Comment: You should be including only **ONE** version of jQuery per page, and it should be the latest. Working with 1.4.2 and jQueryUI 1.8.1 is asking for trouble.

Comment: why using older version for autocomplete?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to include both the js files you can..

```
 <!-- load jQuery 1_8_3 -->
    <script  src="../assets/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var jQuery_1_8_3 = $.noConflict(true);
    </script>

    <!-- load jQuery 1.4.2 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var jQuery_1_4_2= $.noConflict(true);
    </script>
```

Its better to avoid multiple versions in the page..and its better to use appropriate jquery-UI Version with the jquery version

Comment: May be the order is the problem..add this ui file of 1.8.4 under jquery 1.8 file or put jquery 1.4.2 on top..

Answer (score 2):

If you try only these, i think you are good to go:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js">
</script>
```

`No need to add other versions of jquery.`

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because you are including jQuery 2 times. An old version and a newer version.

I would recommend you try and use the most recent versions of both jQuery and jQuery UI and check if everything still works.