# Avoid jQuery conflict with multiple JavaScript library in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I am working on C#.net project, and I use multiple javascript libraries for menu and image sliders and other, but there is a conflict appeared, how can I avoid that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15383186/1238887 -- this should answer your question.

Comment: Please add some code, or error message you get.

Comment: I don't have error message, but the animations don't work well

Comment: So how did you come to the conclusion that it's a conflict?

Answer (score 1):

Right after the load of the jQuery library you call the [$.noConflict();](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) and then all your calls to jQuery are made using the `jQuery` keyword. Example from the [jQuery site](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Comment: but I don't have JQuery code in my .aspx page, all my JQuery code in external .js file, so what I can do?

Comment: @Alaa Do the same, load the jQuery, right after the rest of your jQuery libs, then call the noConfict.