# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'uniqueId' (jquery upgrade)

Tags: jquery, unique-id, jquery-migrate

I have several screens which use jquery validity and jquery tabs and were working fine in 1.7 but now throw an error and the validation is not checked.

Including `<script src="./jquery/jquery.1.9.1/jquery_migrate1.1.1.js"` in the header I see the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'uniqueId'
```

I've been back and loaded the full development bundle and checked everything that I can think of but without success. :-(

My scripts are still working in the Admin area where there is not a javascript menubar - so that may be the issue but I'm at a loss about how to resolve it (Had to upgrade jquery because of problems with some browsers)

I've left a sample of the problem in our beta-testing sandbox area and would very much appreciate some pointers to a solution.

http://districtwebmasters.org/

Log in as user: jquery, password: jquery and look at the 'Profile' screen (top right menubar)

(The tabs stop working when `jquery_migrate` is loaded but seem fine when that's not there)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

I think some problem with your js file

Comment: My guess is that jQuery.noConflict() is the solution but I'm not sure how to use it - and I've tried several ways ;-)   
Still looking for some direction and help

Comment: @Malcom Warden see here for noConflict http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383126/jquery-jqueryui-conflict/15383186#15383186

Comment: Yes, I've read that and tried several different ways to use it - without success, which is why I asked for help